# When is a convex polygon inscribable?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

Defining the diameter of a convex polygon as the maximum possible distance between all pairs of vertices, can we conclude that the convex polygon is inscribable (i.e has all its sides as chords of a circle) if the diameter isn't the diameter of the minimum bounding circle, in which case the circumscribed circle is the minimum bounding circle?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want "the diameter is the diameter of the minimum bounding circle".  Take a long skinny rectangle, which is inscribable.  Now make a pentagon by bending one long side out just a little bit.  No longer inscribable-the circumscribed circle has not changed.

Added:  a figure is below.  The long rectangle and the pentagon have the same diameter, but the pentagon is not inscribable

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, can you add an image please?

Comment: This is close to my point. Following my statement, if I find the diameter of this pentagon, it will be one of the diagonals of the rectangle which also happens to be the diameter of the circle. Now, obviously this circle has to be the minimum bounding circle since every other vertices of the pentagon falls inside or on it. But what happens if a side is stretched outside the circle without changing its diameter (that of the pentagon) but with with  d with do we have an **inscribable** pentagon?